Ping "spike" when pushing repository
I am trying to git push onto a repo on a remote.
When doing so the ping starts going up from a regular ping, to something that I would say is slightly suboptimal.
This also happens on my network (not bound to machine) when OneDrive does it's stuff. (recently uninstalled it from my laptop because of this, to circumvent the problem)
I have not changed a major thing concerning the network in the recent past. Things just started to happen. Other applications apparently do not cause these issues. Streaming, Gaming, web use and all of those micro processes (win11) (weather, stocks) do not cause anything out of the ordinary to happen, as far as I can tell.
But when I do stuff with git (or OneDrive) it slows down the response time to a point where stuff becomes unusable.
The programs even "sabotage" themselves. As you can see below the git pull ended up failing, after causing the ping spike.

